# dplyr: most frequent class per group + conditions, without summarising

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I have a sensor that measures some events (2 categories or more + white noise between them).
  I want to add a window to my data, and classify each window depending on some rules on the proportion of events:

- if more than 90% white noise in the window => all rows must be tagged white noise
- if less than 90% white noise, tag with the most represented event in the window

I found a way of creating my window (but it's not very elegant if you have a better way I'm interested)
  I don't know how to apply the rules and mark the row in the initial data.frame
  Note: I don't want to "summarise" my data, just add a repeated tag to each window.
  In the example my desired output is to add tag "event1" for all window 1&2 observations, "event2" for window 3, and "white noise" for window 4, etc.

```
  df = data.frame(value=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,3,2,3,6,7,8,4,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,3,3,1,5,8,9,9,8,
                          1,-4,-5,-7,-9,-3,-2,-1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,5,7,7,7,6,2))
  df$class="white.noise"; df$class[df$value<1]<-"event2"; df$class[df$value>2]<-"event1"

  # first create a window 
  window.size=13
  df2 = df %>% mutate('window' = rep(1:100, each=window.size)[1:nrow(df)])

  # compute frequencies per window
  df2 %>% group_by(window, class) %>% tally %>% mutate(n=n/window.size*100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can summarise the appropriate tag for each window in a separate dataset, & join that back to the original:

```
df2.sum <- df2 %>%
  group_by(window, class) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(prop = count / sum(count)) %>%
  filter(any(class == "white.noise" & prop >= 0.9) | (class != "white.noise")) %>%
  filter(prop == max(prop)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  rename(new.class = class) %>% select(window, new.class)

> df2.sum
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  window   new.class
   <int>       <chr>
1      4 white.noise
2      5      event1
3      3      event2
4      1      event1
5      2      event1

> left_join(df2, df2.sum, by = "window")
   value       class window   new.class
1      1 white.noise      1      event1
2      1 white.noise      1      event1
3      1 white.noise      1      event1
4      2 white.noise      1      event1
5      2 white.noise      1      event1
6      1 white.noise      1      event1
7      2 white.noise      1      event1
8      1 white.noise      1      event1
9      3      event1      1      event1
10     2 white.noise      1      event1
...
```

Comment: thanks for you nice answer and sorry to reply with delay; It works as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Some enhancement to Z.Lin's answer. I think it is better to wrap classifying logic into separate function first.

```
library(dplyr)

classify_window <- function(class_vec) {
  is_white_noise <- class_vec == "white.noise"
  if (mean(is_white_noise) > 0.9) {
    return("white.noise")
  } else {
    class_no_noise <- class_vec[!is_white_noise]
    class_table <- table(class_no_noise)

    return(names(class_table)[which.max(class_table)])
  }
}

df2_summary <- df2 %>%
  group_by(window) %>%
  summarise(tag = classify_window(class))

df2_tagged <- df2 %>% left_join(y = df2_summary, by = "window")
df2_tagged
```

Comment: thanks for you nice answer and sorry to reply with delay; It works as I expected. I guess there is no simple way to do it other than some conditions and then a merge..